# worklight adapter not calling from javascript

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Adpater is working, checked from calling Adapter option.
but invoking from Javascript no response is getting
pass is getting value say 123456,
but not getting response, no sucssess , no failure.

POST.xml

```
    <displayName>POST</displayName>
    <description>POST</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>164.100.222.200</domain>
            <port>80</port>

            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>60000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>60000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="trackerLogin" />
    <procedure name="setTrackerLocation" />
    <procedure name="getTrackerLocation" />
    <procedure name="updateStatus" />
</wl:adapter>
```

// POST-impl.js

```
         function trackerLogin() {
        var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : '/WomenSafety/api/TrackerLogin/123456789012345?Password=123456'
    };return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    }
```

//    Main.js

```
     function login(pass)
    {
        busyIndicator.show();
        //var imei='123456789012345';

        if(pass!=='')
            {

             var invocationData = {
                     adapter : "POST",
                     procedure : "trackerLogin",
                     parameters : []
                 };

             WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
                 onSuccess : function(resp) {                       
                                  alert('1111');    
                                  },
                 onFailure : function(resp) {
                      alert('2222');        
                      },
             });

        /*  var ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000; 
            var options = {   
                      onSuccess : loginSuccess, 
                      onFailure : loginFailure,
                      timeout : ONE_MINUTE
                    };


         var invocationData = {
                 adapter : 'POST',
                 procedure : 'trackerLogin',
                 parameters : [imei,pass]
             };*/

        // WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
         alert('@@-'+pass);

            }

        else
            {
            alert('Enter Password');
            }
        busyIndicator.hide();
    }
 function loginSuccess(result)
{
//var status=result.statusCode;
alert('1111');
if(status==200)
    {
    alert('Login'); 
    }
     else
    {alert('Network Error');}
  }
  function loginFailure(result)
        {alert('Server Error');}
```

Comment: I would imagine there is something wrong here: `path : '/WomenSafety/api/TrackerLogin/123456789012345?Password=123456'`, how do you know this is correct?

Comment: @IdanAdar i run the Adapter by, RightClick->RunAs->CallMobileFirstAdapter the response shows in browser, but same function does not run by js call, i need sol.today, is ant http adapter example with pat as  URL not by xml

Comment: Please write in proper English... and if you "need a solution today" then don't open a question on stack overflow. Open a PMR.

Comment: @IdanAdar , ok, so is code correct? how to know `WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
` is called

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that in the adapter XML you are point in the `host` property to an actual IP address of the server the adapter should connect to. i.e **not** `localhost`
2. Make sure the device and the MobileFirst Server are **connected to the same network**
3. Print the error you receive in the client once the adapter request fails, and act upon it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1212_paris/1212_paris.html

In the client-side, place `alert()`s before, inside, and after function to make sure you actually enter it (you can also debug your JavaScript in the Chrome DevTool with breakpoints...), and print the values of the objects you pass to see what is happening there.

You can also use Wireshark to inspect the network to see what is happening after the request was sent.

If you don't get anything, it sounds like a network problem.

Comment: Now its working,code and IP is correct,before i call adpater in main.js,now i call in initOptions.js